# Remove or replace multiple strings in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a powershell script that gets data from our AD clients and renames some properties. My question now is about telephone numbers that are not in the same format as others.

Some numbers are right. Some are partially right (the first 5 digits are wrong) and should be corrected by removing the first 5 digits. Some are completely wrong (then it's the same entry as in mobile) and the number should be removed

I just want to get the extension line and not the full telephone number nor the mobile number. If we look at this example of 3 entries the First one is correct.

current result:

```
                                 (this one)
  Surname  Givenname SAM         telefonnummer    mobile      ipphone emailaddress DistinguishedName
1  a       b         ad          10               012 9999
2  c       d         cd          (01)453-345      012 9998
3  d       e         de          012 9997         012 9997
```

Expected result:

```
                                 (this one)
  Surname  Givenname SAM         telefonnummer    mobile      ipphone emailaddress DistinguishedName
1  a       b         ad          10               012 9999
2  b       d         cd          345              012 9998
3  c       e         de                           012 9997
```

My code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
get-aduser -filter * -properties SamAccountName, Name, telephonenumber, SamAccountName, mobile, ipphone, EmailAddress, DistinguishedName, GivenName, Surname  |
Where-Object {($_.DistinguishedName -match "OU=Employee") -and ($_.Name -inotmatch ".*1.*|.*2.*|.*mobil.*|.*Platz.*") } | 
Select-Object (
    @{N='Nachname'; E={$_.Surname}},
    @{N='Vorname'; E={$_.GivenName}},
    @{N='Kuerzel'; E={$_.SamAccountName}},
    @{N='Telefonnummer'; E={$_.telephonenumber.Replace("(01)453-","") }},     <---------
    @{N='Mobile'; E={$_.mobile}},
    @{N='Schnellwahl'; E={$_.ipphone}}, 
    @{N='E-Mail Adresse'; E={$_.EmailAddress}},
    @{N='Abteilung';E={($_.DistinguishedName.Split("=,")[3])}} ) |
Sort-Object -Property Abteilung, Surname |
    export-csv -path \\li\st.csv
```

I had no problem to replace the public number to get the extension but I couldn't figure out how to remove the whole mobile phone number but keep the right numbers.

Comment: I'm pretty unsure if I got what you're trying to do. You may elaborate more detailed what's the situation before and what's the expected result. Please share one or two representative examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's all about "telefonnummer" aka Telephone Number. I have about 150 entries and a bunch of them have "(01)453-" in front of the extension line and I want that part removed what is working in my Code. Some others have a wrong number there (mobile phone number) that I want removed completely. I will try to edit my question to make everything clearer.

Comment: If you have some numbers the way you want and some numbers not you will have to include a conditional replace ... if I've got you right.

Comment: Some numbers are right. Some are partially right (the first 5 digits are wrong) and should be corrected by removing the first 5 digits. Some are completely wrong (then it's the same entry as in mobile) and the number should be removed .

Comment: I got this. ;-)  You will have to create conditions to check what case you have and act accordingly.

Comment: So basically, you want `@{N='Telefonnummer'; E={if ($_.telephonenumber -eq $_.mobile) { "" } else {$_.telephonenumber.Replace("(01)453-","")} }}`?

Comment: yep... that did it... Thank you very much.

Comment: You could have asked how to remove the telephone number if it is equal to the mobile number.  ;-)   ... sometimes it's easier to ask a complex question in your native language ... if you need/like try this [https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/home?forum=powershell_de](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/home?forum=powershell_de)

Comment: ... or another place with some experienced German speaking Powershellers : [https://www.mcseboard.de](https://www.mcseboard.de)